# How to set Content-Type in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use this code to show an image in php

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('test.jpg');
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

It is working in a simple php file, but it's not working in a codeigniter controller. I'm using this method:

```
public function render_image() {
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg('uploads/test.jpg');

    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
}
```

I also tried using this code, but its not helping:

```
$computedImage = 'path/to/the/image.ext';
$this->load->helper('file');
$this->output->set_content_type(get_mime_by_extension($computedImage))->set_output(file_get_contents($computedImage));
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Well, what you did last should work (see [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_content_type)). What result do you get? What is the output of the `get_mime_by_extension()` call?

Comment: @giorgio The output of `get_mime_by_extension()` is "image/jpeg" but i get "The image cannot be displayed, because it contains errors."

Comment: My guess is that there is something wrong with your image itself. Can you open the created image with a normal image viewer? What do you see in dev tools when you try to open the image?

Comment: No i can't open the created image in image viewer. in dev tools, there is a img tag with src and alt that says "The image cannot be displayed, because it contains errors."

Comment: maybe your image error, you should try another image for testing

Comment: I tried with another image, but still no luke. like i was said, it's working with simple php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the hook. i'm using "post_controller_constructor" hook. i put my code in `__construct()` and everything is working.